# Upload arquivo .txt removendo acentos php

Tags: php

Preciso de algum modo para que eu faça upload de um arquivo .txt e todo o texto seja armazenado em uma `array` para depois varer este `array` e retirar todos os acentos do texto, após isso gerar o arquivo .txt sem os acentos ? (Tirar os acentos do conteúdo que esta dentro do arquivo.txt).

Comment: Armazenado em um array? Como assim? Uma linha por entrada?

Comment: É algo do tipo, não sei se por `array` mas preciso ler o arquivo para tirar os acentos certo ? Existe algum outro jeito ?

Comment: Mas quer fazer upload primeiro certo?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="txt">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $file = $_FILES['txt'];
    $dir = 'tests/'; // ajustar nome diretório destino
    $fileName = 'new_txt.txt'; // ajustar nome do ficheiro
    move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $dir.$fileName);
    $text = utf8_encode(file_get_contents($dir.$fileName);
    $search = explode(",","ç,æ,œ,á,é,í,ó,ú,à,è,ì,ò,ù,ä,ë,ï,ö,ü,ÿ,â,ê,î,ô,û,å,e,i,ø,u");
    $replace = explode(",","c,ae,oe,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,y,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u");
    $new_text = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
    $file = fopen($dir.$fileName, 'w');
    fwrite($file, $new_text);
    fclose($file);
    echo 'VELHO TEXTO:<br><br>' .$text. '<br><br>';
    echo 'NOVO TEXTO:<br><br>' .file_get_contents($dir.$fileName);
}
```

Ajuste onde comentei "ajustar..."

Comment: Está funcionando o upload e a criação do novo arquivo .txt porém não está retirando os acentos.

Comment: Deu algum erro?

Comment: Não, só no `echo` os acentos ficam com um "?". Assim Lu�s Lopes Corr�a.

Comment: editei, compare as dois e diga @Kevin.F

Comment: Continua igual com os "?". O velho e o novo.

Comment: Estranho @Kevin.F ... Eu tenho um ficheiro só com isso que esta em cima, nem mais nem menos, e corre direitinho

Comment: @Kevin.F tem a certeza que `$dir.$filename` no seu caso também se refere ao destino/caminho do novo ficheiro sem os acentos?

Comment: Sim no meu ficou assim `$dir = 'ArquivoGerado/';` e `$fileName = 'NewArq.txt';` só alterei estas duas linhas.

Comment: E o ficheiro está lá com os acentos ainda? @Kevin.F

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44121/discussion-between-miguel-and-kevin-f).

Comment: Chat @Kevin.F, o link no comentário em cima

Comment: Boa resposta, mas recomendo que busque por duplicatas antes de responder e use o fechamento ou flag. Por exemplo http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[php]+remover+acentos

Comment: Tem toda a razão @GuilhermeNascimento, não tenho esse hábito ainda... Presumo sempre que isso tem de partir de quem faz a pergunta